# How to route among SOAP APIs using WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am adding some new fine grained APIs to an existing WCF service. The purpose of this redesign is to accomplish better parallelism instead of long running chunky calls.

To maintain backward compatibility, I need to route the old API requests to the new ones. I have checked WSO2 [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM2xx/Map+the+Parameters+of+your+Backend+URLs+with+the+API+Publisher+URLs) and [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Change+the+Default+Mediation+Flow+of+API+Requests). I see guidance on mediation which I believe will help me achieve what I am looking for. However, I am unable to find any documentation on how below scenarios could be achieved for SOAP based APIs.

1. Transform parameter values from one data type to another before routing to a different API like read values from an object and create an XML before calling another API.
2. Consolidate response from two or more APIs within API manager before sending back to client.

Please share if there are any samples or documentation around this.

Comment: Didn't you try following doc for the first question?
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Transforming+API+Message+Payload

Comment: Here is a sample scenario for API Manager. https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c You can get an idea from this. Also, follow the documentation that Sajith has mentioned.